Oracle NVL2 inequality condition
I've been struggling with Oracle's [SQL] NVL2 function. Is there a way to implement and "inequality condition" into it? I keep getting errors of "invalid arguments".
I've been looking around online and on this site and can't find anything.
My statement looks as follows:
NVL2(1<2,"yes","no")


I don't think NVL2 is appropriate. I suggest using CASE. Refer to this 

Syntax is
NVL2 (expr1, expr2, expr3)

whose purpose is:

NVL2 lets you determine the value returned by a query based on whether a specified expression is null or not null.

(it is about expr1; in your case, you're checking whether 1 is less than 2 - that's a Boolean expression, but it doesn't say whether expr1 evaluates to null or not).


If expr1 is not null, then NVL2 returns expr2.
If expr1 is null, then NVL2 returns expr3.



According to what you said (and example you posted: NVL2(1<2,"yes","no")), it seems that you'd want to get yes if 1 < 2 and no otherwise.
In that case, I'd suggest you to use case expression instead, e.g.
SQL> select case when 1 < 2 then 'yes'
  2              else 'no'
  3         end as result
  4  from dual;

RESULT
-------
yes

nvl2 function just doesn't seem to be appropriate in this case.

(Apart from all that, note that you should enclose strings into single quotes, not double ones).
